# Comma before indirect speech

Tags: commas, indirect-speech

> For instance, you can tell them “I expect you to come to class on time,” or “Do not bully.”

Do I need a comma between "them" and "I"?

Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comma is always used before a quotation that is a complete  sentence:

> My father always said, “Be careful what you wish for.”

M-W defines quotation as:

> something that a person says or writes that is repeated or used by
>   someone else in another piece of writing or a speech

Perhaps, regarding your example, you are thinking that because the words within quotation marks do not repeat what someone said, but rather suggest something that may be said in the future, it is not a quotation and should not include the comma.

But common editorial practice, based on the Chicago Manual, Words Into Type, and other such sources, would treat this as a normal quotation and use the comma, because it is intended to convey conversational speech.

A comma is not used when the quotation is not a full sentence, as in

> you can tell them you expect them "to come to come to class on time...

when the quotation renames the subject, as in

> My father’s mantra was “Be careful what you wish for.”

and when quoted material is integral to the sentence, as in

> It's best to begin with a friendly "Hello there!" and move on from
>   there.
>
> His "Hey, pal!" attitude really gets me.

Your example is none of these, and would typically include a comma.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a rule in the proscriptive sense, but if I'm unsure I ask myself if I would pause at this point, if yes, a comma is appropriate

in this case I suspect it is also required